# Apache mod rewrite .htaccess to get params

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can i catch the prams after file name with extension like service.php/view1

for ex:
   service.php/newview1

I want to get it like
   service.php?view=newview1

how do i write mod-rewrite for this

I tried like
   `RewriteRule ^services.php/?([a-zA-Z_]+)$ /services.php?category=$1`

its not matching the service.php/newview1

Answer (score 1):

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.

You need to add `[QSA]` flag to end of your current line

Try adding this regex:
`([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)` as this also matches any integers and hyphens also.

```
RewriteRule ^services.php/?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /services.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I also put the `[L]` flag so it stop processing further rules.