# RewriteRule - encoded php url string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert the url below:

```
index.php?id=585&rurl=%26ts1%3D64%26ts2%3D65%26ts3%3D18
```

to friendly url:

```
/products/%26ts1%3D64%26ts2%3D65%26ts3%3D18/585/my-product-name.html
```

I tried the following but it seems to have a problem with the `rurl` param

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)/([0-9]+)/(.*?).html$ /index.php?id=$2&rurl=$1
```

I am new to this and I can't figure it out.

### UPDATE:

how can I write the rule for the following friendly url

```
/products/585/my-product-name.html?%26ts1%3D64%26ts2%3D65%26ts3%3D18
```

Comment: Your friendly URL isn't look friendly

Comment: %26ts1%3D64%26ts2%3D65%26ts3%3D18 isn't friendly either

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143744/apache-mod-rewrite-htaccess-to-get-params/22144357#22144357)

Comment: what about
/products/585/my-product-name.html?%26ts1%3D64%26ts2%3D65%26ts3%3D18

Comment: something like `/products/my-product-name/lk3jo9ngf` would be better.

Comment: I mean to say that you should remove special characters from your key field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/[^.]+\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: `NE - No Escaping` to unescape the special character